# Jquery Keep Autosuggestion Box Show With Last Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Jquery auto suggestion box, the function is ok. Now I want to when textbox not empty or last input by user, and when user click that textbox again, the suggestion box will appear.

Here is the JS :

```
function suggest(inputString)
    {
        if(inputString.length == 0)
        {
            $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#de_no').addClass('load');
            $.post("autosuggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data)
            {
                if(data.length >0)
                {
                    $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                    $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                    $('#de_no').removeClass('load');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I have ever put this :

```
else if(inputString.length != '')
        {
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
        }
```

But, its not work.
Anyone can give me a suggestions ?
Thanks

Comment: What is inputString? Length return an integer so it will be always different than an empty string

Comment: how are you calling `suggest()`?